# Trying to get a length on a key value on an object which is inside an object within an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I am trying to create a score count for two teams. The score is an array which differentiates by defining if the goal was scored by a home or away team (which is a separate object within the score array). I need to get the count for the number of times a goal has been scored which carries an id of either 1 or 2.

I've tried using query selectors within the DOM, but with the request times, the score doesn't often render properly - the list length doesn't seem to get counted and stays at 0.

I have also tried to filter the count length whilst making a request post-subscription to the service within the component. But this again didn't work. The below code is an example.

This states that goalCount.filter is not a function.

```
getScore(): void {
this.ScoreService.getScore()
.subscribe(score => {
  this.score = score;
  const goalCount = this.score;
  this.count = goalCount.filter((obj) => obj.side.data.id === '1').length;
});
```

}

then {{ count }} is bound to the view, but the above error displays.

console log of score - editor is so bad and formatting it takes ages:

[image: console log of score data]

I expect that when the server sends back a new goalscorer, the ngif decides which column to put it in and the length of that list in the DOM is then printed above it.

e.g

1
Smith, '89

2
Perez, '30
Taylor,'45

awayscore.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { UpdateService } from '../update.service';

import { Stats } from '../stats';
import { StatsService } from '../stats.service';

import { Score } from '../score';
import { ScoreService } from '../score.service';

import { ConfigService } from '../../../shared/config/config.service';
import { Config } from '../../../shared/config/config';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-away-score',
  templateUrl: './away-score.component.html'
})
export class AwayScoreComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input()
  away: Stats;

  private subscription: Subscription;

  config: Config[];

  stats: Stats[];
  score: Score[];

  imageUrl: string;

  count: number;

  constructor(
    private StatsService: StatsService, 
    private ScoreService: ScoreService,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private updateService: UpdateService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfig();
    this.getStat();
    this.getScore();

    this.imageUrl = environment.image_url;

    this.subscription = this.updateService.updateObservables.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'call_score_component') {
        console.log(res.value);
      }
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  getConfig(): void {
    this.configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe(config => this.config = config);
  }

  getStat(): void {
    this.StatsService.getStats()
    .subscribe(stats => this.stats = stats);
  }

  getScore(): void {
    this.ScoreService.getScore()
    .subscribe(score => {
      this.score = score;
    });
  }

}
```

awayscore.component.html:

```
<span *ngIf="away">
  <ng-container *ngIf="config">
    <img *ngIf="away.away_badge.data" class="avatar" [src]="imageUrl + away.away_badge.data.url">
    <h4 
    *ngFor="let c of config;" 
    [style.font-family]="c.header_font.data.font_family"
    [style.text-transform]="c.header_text_case.data.text_case"
    [style.color]="'#' + c.secondary_color.data.hex_code">
      {{ away.away_team }}</h4>
  </ng-container>
  <h1>{{ count }}</h1>
    <ul #awayScore *ngIf="score">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let s of score.data">
        <li *ngIf="s.side.data.side === 'Away'">
          <small>{{ s.goal_scorer }} '{{ s.time_of_goal }}</small>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
   </ul>
</span>
```

score service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()

export class ScoreService {

  url = environment.api_url;

  private scoreURL = this.url + 'score/rows';

  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getScore() {
    return this.http.get(this.scoreURL)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError),
    );
  }

  handleError(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error) {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage = error;
    }
    return _throw(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: A sample stackblitz would help

Comment: Can you give us what console.log(goalCount) prints  and can you show us the HTML?

Comment: sadly, it doesn't log anything as this error comes up: 
vendor.js:1774 ERROR TypeError: goalCount.filter is not a function

To be honest, I think I know what to do. I need to filter out the side.data.id and push them to an array - when I do that, I can get the length on that array.

Comment: @Apex I have created a small demo based on what I understood. Is this what you are looking for? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-football-score-observable

Comment: @Saksham - thanks, man. Appreciate the effort. It's not quite, unfortunately. I need the score to appear above that. So to print 1 for team A and 1 for team B - so basically to print the length for team A scorers and length for team B scorers.  Or something like that.

Comment: hi mate, pls console.log(score), so we can see how your intial object does look like.

Comment: sure. I'll stick it in the original question.

Comment: @sagat console log is up there in picture format as the editor here totally sucks.

Comment: Do you do any mapping in the serviceClass? Could u provide it too if so. regards

Comment: could u try. this.score = score.data? Your log looks like the data is stored in the data key.

Comment: @sagat I'm accessing data via the view. I'll stick an awayscore component up it's exactly the same as the homescore component and the score service

Comment: @sagat the whole thing is up there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an array but its not. Your score contains a property data which is an array. Try this out:

```
getScore(): void {
this.ScoreService.getScore()
.subscribe(score => {
  this.score = score.data;
  const goalCount = this.score;
  this.count = goalCount.filter((obj) => obj.side.data.id === '1').length;
});
```

Comment: smashing - well spotted! Totally missed it. 

slight tweak: this.count = goalCount.filter((obj) => obj.side.data.side === 'Away').length; - works great! Thanks